# MULTISITE: Password issue and Error Cant access site

Tags: multisite

I have recently installed Wordpress Multisite on my domain https://matrixsolutionsnetwork.com. I haven't had any issues at this point with the installation. I successfully added the SEO and Security components to the foundation of the network and added a subdirectory.

Last night I was able to start working on the homepage of the main network site. Saved and went to bed. This morning I sat at my computer and saw the login popup. When I attempted to login back i got nowhere.

I attempted several times to access the site via the admin login page several times with the password created at the time I set up the account. I triple checked to make sure both the username and password were entered correctly. Even attempted to use email address instead of username. I also attempted in multiple browsers. Chrome (primary), Firefox, and Edge. No results.

I then attempted to reset my password in order to gain access. I was able to do a reset following normal processes (clicking link sent to registered email and then putting in new password). Again, still no access to the admin back office.

Then I attempted to change the password in the phpmyadmin under the user database table. I was able to gain access for a little while on firefox but still not chrome or Edge. About an hour ago, I was notified that a password change was requested. At that time I had access to the site and did no such thing.

I went back to login and again, no access granted. After going back to the phpmyadmin table and updating the password again, now all I get when going to the /wp-admin page or even the main page with the coming soon placement...I get one word at the top left of my browser "Error".

I have absolutely no clue why this issue started in the first place and no clue why the reset has been causing so much problem both on the WordPress front end to reset path as well as the PHPMyAdmin path. Unfortunately, the web host I have; Dreamhost, does not provide any support for WordPress multisite so I am at a complete loss on how to troubleshoot this issue.

Does anyone have experience with this kind of issue or come across anyone else who has had this issue occur?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect 'credential sharing' (and not by choice). Perhaps someone was able to get your credentials while you were logged in overnight? Another possibility is browser or site caching; so clear those.

If my site, I'd change credentials everywhere (hosting, FTP, WP database, WP admin users). If necessary through myphpAdmin database access. I would then update everything (WP, themes, plugins; the theme/plugins via manual download/upload from the repository; WP through the Update page).

I would also create a new admin-level user, with a strong password, then sign in as that user (to ensure it works), then deleting (or lowering priveleges to 'subscriber'). I'd also look for unknown files in all folders (since you reinstalled everything, a date sort of the file list will make those stand out). And I would look at my Child Theme files (especially the Child Theme functions.php file.)

Your site may not be hacked, it could be as simple as caching. My procedure for cleaning hacked sites is [here](https://securitydawg.com/recovering-from-a-hacked-wordpress-site/).

Report back with your solution; that's always helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

### Same problem i am facing with multisite i configured 4 websites for different domains last time i was able to login but not right now

There is one solution you have to disable the code from config file for multisite 
Like this .

```
/*
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'allergitest.se');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define( 'SUNRISE', 'on' );
*/
```

then your old password will work and you will also be able to change the password from mysql wp user table

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem in by making true the second line of code in `wp-config.php`

```
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
```

Hope it works for every one.